# how to get only the values of sqlite not the column name, then show them to the user in html?

Tags: html, sqlite, web, flask

I'm making a simple web application using flask where the user can share his recipes with other users.

In summary, you should enter the ingredients of a recipe and the steps, I then insert those into a sqlite database, and then show them, which is my problem, I get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7nGj.png

which is definitely what not I'm looking for.

I want to get only the values (the steps of making burger) without the column name ('direction') , this is my code:

```
@app.route("/recipes")
@login_required

def recipes():

# gets all the recipes
recipes = db.execute("SELECT * FROM recipes;")

# list of all the direction, for each recipe
directions_list = []

# loops through directions table and gets each direction for each recipe
for recipe in recipes:
    dirs = {}
    directions = db.execute("select direction from directions where recipe_id = :recipe_id", recipe_id = recipe['id'])
    dirs = directions
    directions_list.append(dirs)

print(directions_list, file=sys.stderr)

return render_template("recipes.html", recipes = recipes, directions_list = directions_list)
```

and this is my HTML code where I should represent those data:

```
{% block main %}
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
    {% for recipe in recipes %}
      <div class="col mb-3">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{recipe['name']}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{recipe['description']}}</p>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                Prep: {{recipe['prep']}}m
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                Cooking: {{recipe['cooking']}}m
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                Ready in: {{recipe['ready']}}m
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
              {% for direction in directions_list %}
              <li>{{directions_list[recipe['id']-1]['direction']}}</li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}


is there any easier and better way to show those recipe steps? and maybe if I could list each of them as a bullet list element?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7nGj.png
```

Comment: Welcome! Please don't use images for adding code examples, just paste it instead. Tip: Read the guideline on how to ask a good question ->  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This loop never uses `direction`, that should get your attention.

```
   {% for direction in directions_list %}
                  <li>{{directions_list[recipe['id']-1]['direction']}}</li>
```

But what should it iterate over? Isn't it the member of `directions_list` that corresponds to this recipe? (ie `recipe['id'] - 1)`

In pure python, this should give the desired result<sup>*</sup>:

```
for recipe in recipes:
    for direction in directions_list[recipe['id'] - 1]:
        print(direction['direction'])
```

---

<sup>*</sup>The suggested code is based on the assumption that the `execute` method returns a list of dictionaries.